# Cannot compile xamarin.ios binding project

Tags: xamarin.ios, nsobject

I am creating a binding project for Xamarin.ios. I have done ApiDefinition.cs and Structs.cs. When I rebuild my binding project I am getting fillowing two errors in visual studio

1. > Error CS0308  The non-generic type 'NSObject' cannot be used with type arguments
2. > Error CS0111  Type 'LSMAHandlerPincode' already defines a member called
   >   'SendInvitationForUsecase' with the same parameter

For the 2nd issue I can see two methods with same name and the same types are there. But I don't know how to resolve that issue since I need both methods defined in the objective-c framework.

These are my duplicate methods

```
    [Abstract]
    [Export("sendInvitationForUsecase:toEmail:withReference:andNotify:")]
    void SendInvitationForUsecase(LSMAUsecase usecase, string email, [NullAllowed] string reference, [NullAllowed] Action<LSMAPincodeStatus_t, NSString> block);

    // @required -(void)createInvitationForUsecase:(NSObject<LSMAUsecase> * _Nonnull)usecase withReference:(NSString * _Nullable)reference andNotify:(void (^ _Nullable)(LSMAPincodeStatus_t, NSString * _Nullable))block;
    [Abstract]
    [Export("createInvitationForUsecase:withReference:andNotify:")]
    void CreateInvitationForUsecase(LSMAUsecase usecase, [NullAllowed] string reference, [NullAllowed] Action<LSMAPincodeStatus_t, NSString> block);
```

Does anybody know how can I solve these 2 issues? Please help me.
Thanks
**UPDATE**

Please find the link for ApiDefinition.cs and Structs.cs
https://www.dropbox.com/s/aa22vg9r7mme636/Files.rar?dl=0

Link for the framework
https://github.com/sightcall/iOS-UniversalSDK

Comment: Can you provide the file ApiDefinition.cs ,Structs.cs and the framework so that I can test it on my side.

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I updated the question with the links. You can download the folder which includes 2 files and the SDK.

Comment: I will check it.

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Thanks :)

Comment: Check the answer of Cole . https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/155927/cannot-build-xamarin-ios-binding-project

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT what would be the solution for 1st issue?

Comment: [BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]
[Model]